# <STDIN> vs $name substring search - one works other doesn't

Tags: perl

I am an old programmer in MASM, perl, Qbasis and HTML but have been out of it for 20 years. Now I have an online store and want to make some of my own scripts again in perl.

So, now, I am searching thru some CSV files to find customer emails in them. My perl script works fine if I use

`my $searchName = 'mchanna@gmail.com';`

but if I want to set it up to get a value from the console like this

`chomp(my $searchName = <STDIN>);`

it doesnt find them. Here is the whole script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;  

my @filenames = ("2019 Sales.csv", "2020 Sales.csv", "2021 Sales.csv", "2022 Sales.csv", "2023 Sales.csv" );
my $file = "";
my $count = 0;

my $searchName = 'mchanna@gmail.com';
chomp(my $searchName = <STDIN>);

foreach $file (@filenames) {
    open(FH, '<', $file) or die $!;
    while( my $line = <FH>) {
        if (index(lc($line), lc($searchName)) != -1) {
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
    close(fh);
}
print "$searchName has $count matches found\n";
```

Any suggestions?

I tried single and double quotes, read thru tones of web pages on index, chomp and strings in perl.

Thought it was because of the `\n` on `<STDIN>` but chomp made no difference

There has to be some little thing I am missing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're using a unixy build of Perl, and that you're reading from a Windows text file (CR LF endings.). If so, using `$searchName =~ s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp( $searchName )` will fix it.

Comment: Is this a CGI script or something you're running from a command line?

Comment: If you run this form a command line,  1) how _exactly_ do you run it, and  2) what _exactly_ does it print?

Comment: You say manual input of `'mchanna@gmail.com` doesn't work while hardcoded does?  In that case try dumping both strings to see the difference. E.g. it could be a strange encoding problem of `@` tho I'm not aware of any way to represent it other than in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- You're not doing anything with CGI in this script, so you can ditch `use CGI;`
- Whenever I have problems with input, I echo it back to see what I'm getting. You're already doing that in your last print statement, but it could be **better** if you do it this way:

```perl
print "'$searchName' has $count matches found\n";
```

By putting the variable's value inside single quotes in the double-quoted string, it makes it easier to see if you're getting what you expect.  If, for example, there's extra whitespace on the end of your values, you'd see something like this:

```
'mchanna@gmail.com ' has 0 matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code with files that contain `mchanna@gmail.com`, I find that string. Since we don't see your input, I suspect either that the email is not in any of those files or that's not what you are actually have as your search term.

After you get the input, output it so you can see what it is:

```
chomp( my $searchTerm = <STDIN> );
print "Search term is <$searchTerm>\n";
```

If you don't see the problem there, you might have to try harder:

```
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
Dump( $searchTerm );
```

### Extra stuff

Beyond that, you are doing a lot of work that Perl can do for you. Instead of handling all of the files yourself, playing with case, and so on, let Perl do that:

```
my $searchName = shift @ARGV;

my $count = 0;
while( <> ) {
    $count++ if m/\Q$searchName/i;
}

print "$searchName has $count matches found\n";
```

You'd run that like:

```
% perl program.pl mchanna@gmail.com *.csv
```

Not that you need a one-liner, but the same shortcuts make that easy. The `BEGIN` and `END` are there to do something once at the beginning and once at the end:

```
$ perl -lne '$c++ if m/\Q$s/} BEGIN{$s=shift} END{print qq($s found $c time)' mchanna@gmail.com *.csv
mchanna@gmail.com found 1 time
```

But really, it looks like it might be better to import that stuff into a database. Something simple like SQLite could work (with an index on email). Then the database handles almost everything you are doing, and faster if you have lots of data.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't at least part of the problem that $searchname has been initialized twice with `my`??

`my $searchName = 'mchanna@gmail.com'; chomp(my $searchName = <STDIN>);`

Def follow @Packy's suggestion to print/echo input as you test.

But try your same script without the second `my`.